# Python: When I Call "Sub", It Wont Be Reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I made this simple code in attempt to demonstrate a problem I am having with Python. Here is the code:

```
def Main():
    print("In Main.")
    while(True):
        TheInput1 = input("Go To Sub?:")
        if(TheInput1.lower() == "y"):
            Sub()
            break
        elif(TheInput1.lower() == "n"):
            print("bye")
            quit()
        else:
            print("what?")
Main()
def Sub():
    print("In Sub");
    while(True):
        TheInput2 = input("Go To Main?:")
        if(TheInput2.lower() == "y"):
            Main()
            break
        elif(TheInput2.lower() == "n"):
            print("bye")
            quit()
        else:
            print("what?")
Sub()
```

Whenever I input y it will give me an error instead of going to Sub. Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 11, in <module>
  File "python", line 6, in Main
NameError: name 'Sub' is not defined
```

I'm sure the solution is quite simple but I don't know how to make this happen.

Comment: Place the definition of Sub() before you call Main(). Python interprets files sequentially, so Sub() isn't defined when you make the call to Main() right after you define Main()

Comment: @Craig I also want it to return to main in the sub definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling main before Sub is defined move your main call below sub.

```
def Main():
    print("In Main.")
    while(True):
        TheInput1 = input("Go To Sub?:")
        if(TheInput1.lower() == "y"):
            Sub()
            break
        elif(TheInput1.lower() == "n"):
            print("bye")
            quit()
        else:
            print("what?")
def Sub():
    print("In Sub");
    while(True):
        TheInput2 = input("Go To Main?:")
        if(TheInput2.lower() == "y"):
            Main()
            break
        elif(TheInput2.lower() == "n"):
            print("bye")
            quit()
        else:
            print("what?")
Main()
Sub()
```

Comment: So, if I have multiple definitions, I put them in order?

Comment: Define all your functions before you make any function calls. The order you make the definitions is not important